# I can't locate a button that is used to delete a record by its xpath in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have an element that is in a table, in this table records with a different id are saved.

This is the type of the delete button

```
<span class=" material-icons notranslate icon" aria-hidden="true">delete</span>
```

This is the relative XPATH:

```
//tr[@id='223']//span[contains(@class,'notranslate icon')][normalize-space()='delete']
```

If I search for it with the ID it finds it but the record I created I don't know what ID it will be, it could be 224 or it could be 14556 so I need to click on that element.

```
<a class="btn btn-icon btn-destructive-sec btn-md md-component ghost text-capitalize text-danger-400 " data-title="Delete " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left " data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this offer letter template?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/recruiting/offer_letter/templates/241" data-original-title="" title="">
<span class=" material-icons notranslate icon" aria-hidden="true">delete</span>
```

When I search for an element by xpath it finds it but the next element's ID will be different and I can't find it there anymore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Google this **How to handle dynamic web tables in selenium**. You should get a plenty of solutions. Am posting one of the google search results here https://www.guru99.com/handling-dynamic-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
rows = WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=5).until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="table_ls"]tbodytr')))
for row in rows:
    date = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]').text
    closing_price = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[2]').text
    fluctuation_range = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[3]').text
    row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[4]').click()
    row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[5]').get_attribute('value')
    ...
    ...
...
```

Hello, I have not used selenium in Java, but please allow me to use my thought process in python. I have omitted some initialization code and hope you can understand it. First, rows is List of elements in each row of the table. When I want to access which cell of a row I do it in a loop, like above, so you can make sure that the xpath you use has nothing to do with the changing id.